# how to check/handle for multiple match objects returned by `re` module in better way

Tags: python, regex

I have a situation where I have to handle multiple variable regex match objects for checking `NoneType`, e.g.:

```
import re
test_str = "test string"
test_1 = re.search(r'test_pattern_1', test_str)
test_2 = re.search(r'test_pattern_2', test_str)
test_3 = re.search(r'test_pattern_3', test_str)
test_4 = re.search(r'test_pattern_4', test_str)

if test_1:
  test_1.group()
if test_2:
  test_2.group()
if test_3:
  test_3.group()
if test_4:
  test_4.group()
```

This doesn't seem to me as a cleaner approach to check for multiple match regex objects, so is there any better way to handle this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing with the group after? Just printing them? Store them to somewhere?

Comment: yea, basically I am storing group values and returning those to diff. function for other operations.

Comment: Do you use the same "test_pattern" in all four searches? Please also include an example of what is done to the results.

Comment: No "test_pattern" is different for all 4 match objects and also I am using each match objects results with `split` and other operations to use results to resolve my required issues.